# Resolve not working in loop Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, promise

Hi I have a problem running a loop and getting the return data using `Promises`.

I have a `getStudentMarks` method for getting students marks from the database in subject wise.

```
getStudentMarks: function(studentId, studentStandard) {
    console.log("getStudentMarks invoked...");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        r.table('student_subjects').filter({
            "studentId": studentId,
            "studentStandard": studentStandard
        }).pluck("subjectId", "subjectName").run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                reject(err);
            } else {
                cursor.toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err
                    } else {
                        console.log(result.length);
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                            studentSubjectArray = result;

                            var studentMarksSubjectWiseArray = [];
                            studentSubjectArray.forEach(function(elementPhoto) {
                                r.table('student_marks').filter({
                                    "studentId": studentId,
                                    "subjectId": studentSubjectArray.subjectId
                                }).run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        throw err;
                                        reject(err);
                                    } else {
                                        cursor.toArray(function(err, result_marks) {
                                            var studnetMarksDataObject = {
                                                subjectId: studentSubjectArray.subjectId,
                                                subjectName: studentSubjectArray.subjectName,
                                                marks: result.marks
                                            };
                                            studentMarksSubjectWiseArray.push(studnetMarksDataObject);
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            resolve(studentMarksSubjectWiseArray);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm invoking the method by,

```
app.post('/getStudentMarks', function(req, reqs) {
    ubm.getStudentMarks(req.body.studentId, req.body.studentStandard)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('return data: ' + data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

When I run the code its working absolutely fine there is no error. I get all the student marks object in the `studentMarksSubjectWiseArray` array. But the problem is even before the `studentSubjectArray` loops gets completed, the resolve is getting executed and I'm getting a blank array as return. How do I solve the problem. I understand that I'm not doing the `Promises` right. I'm new to `Promises` so I'm not being able to figure out the right way.

Comment: Note that like a return, execution in your scope is stopped after a throw : `reject`  will not occur.

Comment: @L.Meyer I didn't get you. I think the problem is with my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because inside your `studentSubjectArray.forEach` statement you perform set of asynchronous operations `r.table(...).filter(...).run()` and you push their result into the array. However, those actions finish after you perform the `resolve()`, so the `studentMarksSubjectWiseArray` is still empty. In this case you would have to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

```
let promisesArray = [];
studentSubjectArray.forEach((elementPhoto) => {
    let singlePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // here perform asynchronous operation and do the resolve with single result like r.table(...).filter(...).run()
        // in the end you would perform resolve(studentMarksDataObject)

        r.table('student_marks').filter({
            "studentId": studentId,
            "subjectId": studentSubjectArray.subjectId
        }).run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                reject(err);
            } else {
                cursor.toArray(function(err, result_marks) {
                    var studnetMarksDataObject = {
                        subjectId: studentSubjectArray.subjectId,
                        subjectName: studentSubjectArray.subjectName,
                        marks: result.marks
                    };
                    resolve(studnetMarksDataObject);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    promisesArray.push(singlePromise)
});

Promise.all(promisesArray).then((result) => {
    // here the result would be an array of results from previously performed set of asynchronous operations
});
```

Comment: I read about it. But how do I apply in my code that's something I'm not getting. If you could provide a snippet it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: I have just updated the answer to show how it could be done with use of `Promise.all`

Comment: Thank you. Let me try the code, will get back to you asap.

Comment: So each time I resolve singlePromise I'm basically pushing an object into the promisesArray right?

Comment: Yes, at each iteration you push promise that resolves to single object, and when you perform `Promise.all` on this iterable (array), you get all the objects in array

Comment: Thanks for the Help. It was great and most importantly you did almost everything more than just a snippet.